# Sharepoint 2010 stsadm createsite command in command line giving me error that "The web application url http://xxxx cannot be reached

Tags: sharepoint, command-line, stsadm

I was trying to run the createsite stsadm command from command line in sharepoint2010 and I am getting error that is "The web application url http:// cannot be reached....". I have searched the web and most of the blogs/sites referring to this same kind of error from the visual studio code. They have asked to change the target in VS to 64 bit. But here i am not running from the visual studio and i am only trying to run the createsite stsadm command in the commandline.

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: The user with which you are trying, does that have enough rights?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running SharePoint 2010, you should consider moving to PowerShell.  The PowerShell command for this would be:

Get-SPWebTemplate
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"
New-SPSite -Url "" -OwnerAlias "" -Template $template